# Always keep EC2 Instance running even if it was stopped based on its TAG

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tags, schedule

I have some EC2 instances with specific TAGs that are monitored by event bridge and if some action occur the instance must be stopped and then started again. This was already done. But sometimes the instance didn't start again (looks like the event bridge don't get the event of stopped instance to automatically start it).

Which is the best way to schedule a script or something else to every minute check all the stopped instances with specific TAG and then start it?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Normally to ensure you have 1 instance running, you put them in autoscaling group with desired capacity of 1.

Comment: Would it be suitable simply to **Reboot** the instance rather than doing a Stop and Start? That would only require a single call.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, thank you for your response, but in my application I really need to power on an instance that is stopped, the simply reboot don't fit my needs.

Comment: @Marcin maybe this could be a good idea, I will need to check how I will perform this.

In my point of view the easier way would be an scheduled script to check this, I will need to try to implement it.

Comment: @WinnerMartins What extra capability does a Stop & Start give, compared to a Reboot? Are you are attempting to get a new public IP address so that you can scrape websites against their Terms & Conditions? (That is not something that we encourage here.)

Answer (score 0):

In this case I used a Python Lambda function to perform the EC2 start.
And the lambda is scheduled by eventbridge (cloud Watch Events)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).